# Rails 5.1 secrets and Stripe using wrong key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, stripe-payments

I am using

`rails 5.1.2`
`gem 'stripe-rails`

and when I deploy to Heroku I am double checking that the Heroku environment is using the correct Stripe Keys for production by doing the following:

`heroku run rails console --remote heroku`

This opens a ruby console on heroku for me: `irb(main):009:0>` where I then check what Stripe Keys it has by doing the following:

`Rails.application.secrets.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY` => `sk_Live_***************`
`Rails.application.secrets.STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY` => `pk_Live_**************`

I'm assuming that the production environment has the right keys set because of the prefixes `sk_Live` and `pk_Live` but when I try run the following:

`Stripe::BillingPortal::Session.create(customer: 'cus_**LiveID*****',return_url: "http://someurl.com")` it fails and says that  `a similar object exists in live mode, but a test mode key was used to make this request.` The weird thing is that all my other Stripe actions like creating subscriptions are working as expected in production so I am entirely at a loss why this one action creating a BillingPortal is always using a test key and failing.  Obviously it works when I test it locally because that is a test environment and stripe doesn't error. This error exists only on production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few debug steps:

1. Go to your Dashboard request log: [Live mode log](https://dashboard.stripe.com/logs) or [Test mode
   log](https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/logs) and find the exact request that is failing
2. Confirm that it is using a Test mode key
3. On the console before calling the problematic Billing Portal, double check if the Stripe instance is using correct key by

```rb
p Stripe.api_key
Stripe::BillingPortal::Session.create(customer:'cus_**LiveID*****',return_url: "http://someurl.com")
```

Despite your Rails application could have correct secrets, it looks like your Stripe *instance* might still use the test key value from somewhere else.

Comment: You were absolutely right.  The Stripe initializer had hard-coded the test key. Thank you.